# AD-HOC command for installing a package in ubuntu

Tags: ansible, adhoc

Whenever I tried to install the package in ubuntu but it's throwing an error like below following code

But if I tried to ping with slave machine it's look fine

```
172.31.6.185 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "cache_update_time": 1619825195,
    "cache_updated": false,
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"      install 'httpd'' failed: E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate\n",
    "rc": 100,
    "stderr": "E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate"
    ],
    "stdout": "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state information...\nPackage httpd is a virtual package provided by:\n  nginx-core 1.18.0-0ubuntu1\n  apache2 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.1\n\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Reading package lists...",
        "Building dependency tree...",
        "Reading state information...",
        "Package httpd is a virtual package provided by:",
        "  nginx-core 1.18.0-0ubuntu1",
        "  apache2 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.1",
        ""
    ]
}
```

Comment: The problem that is reported is that it cannot install any of the required dependencies. The virtual package `httpd` is required. According to the package manager, this requirement can be fulfilled either by `nginx-core` version `1.18.0-0ubuntu1` or by `apache2` version `2.4.41-4ubuntu3.1`. Neither can be installed without conflicts.

You should find out why none of these packages can be installed, perhaps by trying them individually and see what's the problem.

Comment: I want to install `httpd` only what should I do to avoid the conflicts when to install

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Ubuntu does not have httpd as a package name, which is explained in the following error message:failed: E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate

The Red Hat distribution family (RHEL, CentOS, and Fedora) call it httpd that because technically that's the upstream project name, the Debian distribution family (of which Ubuntu is a descendant) is called apache2.

https://www.thinbug.com/q/58357332

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about try to update your adhoc command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install apache2
```

Comment: Normal installation is ok for what you have mentioned 
But here I have tried to install packages using AD-HOC Command in ansible

Comment: @AKASH-29, what is your ansible adhoc command?

Comment: $ ansible all -m apt -a "name=httpd state=present" -b

Comment: ansible all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=present" -b

Comment: or you can use `ansible all -m command -a "apt update && apt upgrade && apt install apache2" -b`

Comment: ok.. mate i have tried out another service `apache2` it getting install, So there is some problem in `HTTPD` naming